# trying to make div bounce on pageload

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bounce

I am simply trying to make a div bounce when the page is loaded using this JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".test").effect( "bounce", 
              {times:4}, 500 );

});
```

But it isn't working.

Here is a JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jb9mt/)

Why is it not animating when I run the code?

Thanks

Comment: You dd not select the `jquery-ui` extension which is required for the bounce effect.. Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jb9mt/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) for that

Working demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/jb9mt/1/

- http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/